# Time Synchronized Channel Hopping (TSCH) for IEEE 802.15.4e in omnetpp

Tags: omnet++

I want to implement time synchronized channel hopping at MAC layer for my TDMA MAC protocol in OMNET++ simulation framework. That is each node utilizes channel hopping to select the channel and transmit the packet in its own slot. I am looking for time synchronized channel hopping implementation in oment++, does any one have an idea how can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TSCH is not yet implemented in Omnet++. Please have a look to OpenWSn simulator where TSCH is implemented and mainly used.
Good luck :)